# Apache Error - but in a weird way: mydomain.com:80:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: apache

I am facing a kinda strange problem in my Apache error log. I know that this message is not critical, but what throws me of is that apache ist looking for the certificate **at Port 80**
Anybody got an idea?

ports.conf is at default, I tried disabling Port 80 here but it didn't change the problem.

`[Thu Jul 11 18:45:20.311500 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 457] AH01909: mydomain.com:80:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Comment: In order to better help you, please provide your configuration files and log excerpts.  Be sure to omit or obscure any sensitive information.

Comment: What exactly would you need? My error log pretty much only shows this error for all my virtual hosts. apache.conf is at default. mod_ssl enabled, mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Problem solved. I forgot to put "SSLEngine On" into my virtual hosts, that's what caused the error.